# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: when trying to migrate, laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have two new migrations

```
    Schema::create('courriers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('link');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this one

```
    Schema::table('shipments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('courrier_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('courrier_id')->references('id')->on('courriers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Note That I have many table existing, including the `shipments`

But during the migration process in laravel, it has an error that says

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`#sql-2cc_99`, CONSTRAINT `shipments_courrier_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`courrier_id`) REFERENCES `courriers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `shipments` add constraint `shipments_courrier_id_foreign` foreign key (`courrier_id`) references `courriers` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

What is that error?
What to do with it in laravel?

Comment: Your foreign key is unsigned, but the `id` column in the Courriers table is not.

Comment: using increment method will set unsigned automatically on database table column

Comment: Excuse me, i misread the docs. You are right. I have no way to verify this at the moment, lucky guess: Your foreign key column cannot be null? so maybe `nullable()`?